# In terms of EditText imeOptions, which does the average user appreciate more: actionNext or actionDone?

Tags: android, user-interface

In the context of an Android app, I have a handful of EditText's as part of a fairly typical "enter registration details" form.

If I specify android:imeOptions="actionDone" on them, the user gets 'done' option on their soft keyboard which immediately hides the keyboard, which I feel is analogous to hitting the enter key.

If I just leave them as-is, the option defaults to 'next' (until the last EditText) and shifts focus to the next widget without hiding the keyboard, analogous to hitting the tab key.

On a desktop environment I would fully expect my final action on each field to be 'tab', but I also don't have a keyboard covering up half of the form.  I find that on this activity, my co-workers and I usually prefer to hide the keyboard before focusing on the rest of the form, and the back key is not an muscle-memory action for most (lots of designers and devs using other platforms).

From a UX perspective, which is the better option?

[image: android:imeOptions="actionNext"]
[image: android:imeOptions="actionDone"]

Comment: **actionNext** : This makes more sense when  there is a focusable field after the current Edit Text.
**actionDone** : This is used generally for last editable field in Activity/UI/Screen.

Comment: That is how they were intended, yes.

Comment: But I guess there is no hard and fast rule, AFAIK for actionNext or actionDone  You should use what make sense in your app

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I came to.  I'd like to find out what stackoverflow thinks is better UX.

Comment: I prefer the `imeOptions="normal"`. As the name suggests it behaves as the normal user would expect ime to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the user control is almost always the best option, in my opinion.

Setting the button behavior to "done" replicates the functionality of the back soft key, and prevents the user from quickly and easily moving to the next field. The "next" option means that closing the keyboard and jumping to the next field are just a single tap away.

Additionally, leaving the default behavior in place means that your app is consistent with virtually everything else out there, for Android or iOS, which is definitely good for muscle memory.

Comment: Well argued... I have retained the default behaviour and shored some things up to keep it consistent.